# std::tie and lifetimes of objects returned in tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, lifetime

In the code below I have a function which modifies two expensive-to-copy objects, and I am trying to get away without output parameters

```
   struct FatThing {/* some big data members here*/};

   auto processFatThings(FatThing ft1, FatThing ft2)-> std::tuple<FatThing, FatThing> {
      // do smth with those two
      return std::make_tuple(move(ft1), move(ft2));
   }

   auto useProcessFatThings()-> void {
      FatThing ft1, ft2;
      std::tie(ft1, ft2) = processFatThings(move(ft1), move(ft2)); // dangling references?
   }
```

I am a little bit confused now, since compiler do not emit any warning, sanitizers and memcheck are clean, and the code works. But!!! Is not a dangling reference created with std::tie here?

Comment: Why do you think that dangling references are involved? You are not using references anywhere, neither in your function arguments nor in your return types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, no dangling references.  `ft1` and `ft2` will be assigned to the respective elements from the return value of `processFatThings`

See the following code for example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Something {
public:
    Something() {
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
    }
    Something(Something&&) {
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
    }
    Something(const Something&) {
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
    }
    ~Something() {
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
    }
    Something& operator=(const Something&) {
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    Something one, two;
    std::tie(one, two) = std::make_tuple(Something(), Something());
}
```

Live demo here https://wandbox.org/permlink/iG1qIJ2VKL4bljPM

Here you will see that there are 4 constructions, corresponding to `one`, `two` and the two arguments to `make_tuple`.

Then two move constructions for `make_tuple`.

Then there are two copy assignments.  This is the key part here.  The `Something` objects get copied to whatever was "tied" with `std::tie`.

So no dangling references, you get copies/moves!

Comment: Well, if you add the move assignment it is going to use that. I am still a bit confused on how it works, but feel much better now :). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No danging references occur here.  `ft1` and `ft2` are values, and we bind them to references, and the lifetime of `ft1` and `ft2` (who expire at the end of the block) exceeds the references (who expire on the end of the line).

This however:

```
  auto ftings = processFatThings(move(ft1), move(ft2));
  FatThing& ft1 = std::get<0>(ftings);
  FatThing& ft2 = std::get<1>(ftings);
```

is marginally better, as it removes a move construction.  It also lines up with what

```
  auto[ft1,ft2] = processFatThings(move(ft1), move(ft2));
```

does in C++17.

Note that if `FatThing` has big data members *in* it, as opposed to *owned by it*, `move` doesn't help.  An array of 1 billion elements takes 1 billion units of time to move.  A data member that is a vector of 1 billion elements, meanwhile, is much faster to move than copy.  (Vector owns its buffer, it does not store its buffer within it)